# Excel Application Unusable after VBA Program

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project

I have a VBA program in **MS Project**, which opens the Excel application and a spreadsheet, slightly adjusts the spreadsheet and then saves it as a new file so that it can be imported into MS project.

The code work perfectly, it amends the Excel file like I want it to, but after running the code, I open up Excel and it is no longer usable, it just a blank application.

At first I wasn't closing the application or making it visible again (`targetApp.Quit` and `targetApp.Visible=True`), which I though might be causing the problem, but adding both those lines of code didn't solve the problem. Any help or direction would be appreciated, thanks.

Code and screenshot of blank Excel application below:

```
Private Sub processExportExcelSheet()
    If Not ErrorMessage = "" Then Exit Sub

    Dim targetApp As New Excel.Application
    Dim targetWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim targetSheet As Excel.Worksheet

    targetApp.Visible = False
    targetApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    targetApp.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set targetWorkBook = targetApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Exports\Data.xls")
    Set targetSheet = targetWorkBook.Worksheets(1)

    Dim rowCount, columnCount As Integer

    For rowCount = 1 To 10
        For columnCount = 1 To 10
            If targetSheet.Cells(rowCount, columnCount) = "P" _
                Then GoTo exitLoop
        Next columnCount
    Next rowCount

    ErrorMessage = "The data is corrupt"
    GoTo corruptData

exitLoop:
    rowCount = rowCount - 1
    columnCount = columnCount - 1

    If Not rowCount = 0 Then targetSheet.Range(targetSheet.Rows(1), _
        targetSheet.Rows(rowCount)).Delete Shift:=x1Up
    If Not columnCount = 0 Then targetSheet.Range(targetSheet.Columns(1), _
        targetSheet.Columns(columnCount)).Delete Shift:=x1ToLeft

    Dim count, deleteCount As Integer
    count = 1
    deleteCount = 0

    Do While deleteCount < 5
        If targetSheet.Cells(1, count) = "" Then
            targetSheet.Columns(count).Delete Shift:=x1ToLeft
            deleteCount = deleteCount + 1
        Else
            targetSheet.Cells(1, count) = "Title" & count
            count = count + 1
            deleteCount = 0
        End If
    Loop

    count = 2
    deleteCount = 0

    Do While deleteCount < 5
        If targetSheet.Cells(count, 1) = "" Then
            targetSheet.Rows(count).Delete Shift:=x1Up
            deleteCount = deleteCount + 1
        Else
            count = count + 1
            deleteCount = 0
        End If
    Loop
    targetWorkBook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Exports\Data.xlsx", FileFormat:=51

corruptData:
    targetWorkBook.Close
    Kill ("C:\Exports\Data.xls")

    targetApp.ScreenUpdating = True
    targetApp.DisplayAlerts = True
    targetApp.Visible = True
    targetApp.Quit

End Sub
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you explain what this code is *for*?  Why have you coded specifically to deal with file corruption?  What is corrupting what, and why are you writing a workaround for it instead of solving the original problem?  I suspect you need to take a couple steps back and explain the "real" problem.  (See [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).) It's strange that you describe it as *working perfectly* when coding a section of called ***`corruptdata:`***.

Comment: Corrupt probably isn't the best word for me to use in my code. I export the data from the application SAP, and on occasion the data exported has random columns and rows inserted. The code above is looking for the cell containing "P" the name of the first column title and then delete the surplus rows and columns before it. It then checks if any other rows and columns are empty and then delete them too. If it can't find "P" in the first 10 rows and columns, the data exported is wrong. I should probably use 'wrongExportLayout:'

Comment: So, your code checks 100 cells and if none of them contains only the letter "P" then you delete the file. (and the `corruptData:` section runs anyways, every time this procedure is executed.) Not making a whole lot of sense.

Comment: Its also changes the file format from .xls to .xlsx. .xlsx is required for importing the data into MS Project. The data is successful imported into MS project every time, its when I open an excel spread sheet (any spread sheet) after running the code does the excel application not respond correctly.

Comment: Against my better judgement I tried running it - but it won't run for me because undeclared variables and **typos** like `1`'s instead of `l`'s.  **Put `Option Explicit` at the top** of [every] module [always] and try running it.  This will help prevent certain problems by forcing you to properly declare and handle your variables, objects, properties, etc.  Also, you should **reboot** in case there are multiple instances of Excel running (hidden).

Comment: Check Task Manager and make sure an instance of Excel  has not been left running and not been closed properly.

Comment: @Ashleedawg thanks I've now added that and I did have a couple of undeclared variables which I've fixed

Comment: @dbmitch I think this might have been the problem. When I executed the code originally without the targetApp.quit it mustn't have closed excel correctly. So when I did eventually add that line of code, there was still an unclosed excel application open from before (causing the problem). I've now shut down all excel applications and run the code (with targetApp.quit) and excel open perfectly post running the code. Thanks!

Comment: @Jarron - excellent. I will add as answer. Congrats on fixing up code and variables as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Task Manager and make sure an instance of Excel has not been left running and not been closed properly.

If you haven't exited your VBA opened instance of Excel with `.Quit` it will remain active - but hidden - and any dialog boxes generated by your instance will stall attempts to open new instances